# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}-e}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Since we have $\frac00$,I Applied L'Hopital rule :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{\tfrac1x}\times\left(\cfrac{-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}+\cfrac{1}{x(x+1)}\right)$$$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\cfrac{x^2(x+1)(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}-(x+1)\ln(1+x)+x}{x^2(x+1)}$$

But as you can see it is getting very ugly.

Comment: Hint: It is the derivative of $x \mapsto (1+x)^{1/x}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Hint: you probably already know $\lim_{x\to0} (1+x)^{1/x}$, so concentrate on the term in parentheses at the end of the first line: combining them into a single fraction and using l'Hôpital's rule twice more should work. (Note also that there is an algebra error in going from the first line to the second.)

Comment: @Gary: that's true but it leads to the exact same expression as l'Hôpital's rule does.

Comment: @GregMartin I just saw that algebra error thanks. I had to calculate the fractions in parentheses then multiply first term to that. but now according to your hint I should replace the first term with $e$ . am I right?

Comment: Perhaps something like (using series expansions): $$\begin{align}L&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}-e}{x}\\&=e\cdot\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\ln\left(1+x\right)/x-1}-1}{x}\\&=e\cdot\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\left(x-x^{2}/2\right)/x-1}-1}{x}\\&=e\cdot\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-x/2}-1}{x}\\&=e\cdot\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(1-x/2\right)-1}{x}\\&=-\frac{e}{2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that the use of L'Hopital's rule is somewhat circular here, or at the very least overkill, as the given limit is the definition of the derivative of $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/x}$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=e$. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118581/272831) for another such example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{{\frac{1}{x}}\ln(1+x)}-e}{x}\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{{\frac{1}{x}}\ln(1+x)-1}-1}{x}\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{{\frac{1}{x}}\ln(1+x)-1}{x}\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}-1}{2x}\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{2(1+x)}\\
&=\frac{-e}{2}
\end{aligned}

Comment: How you get forth line from the third line? You replace exponent of $e$ on the next line. how this works?

Comment: @soheil I have a simpler answer for you!

Comment: @Physor this answer is also interesting I am trying to understand it :)

Comment: @soheil Please see http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/mat/infiequi.pdf

Comment: @fengbiqian Unfortunately I couldn't open the link :"Hmmm… can't reach this pagewww.vaxasoftware.com took too long to respond"

Comment: @soheil It is called equivalent infinitesimals.

Comment: Oh I got it thank you. in fact we used $e^u\sim 1+u$ where $u\to 0$ here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Taylor series of $${(1+x)}^{1/x}=e(1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{11}{24}x^2+...)$$

If used you get $-e/2$

Comment: Can you give a hint on how to obtain Taylor series of $(1+x)^{1/x}$?

Answer (score 0):

Without series, only L'Hospital
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}-e}{x}
$$
we get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\left(-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}(1+x)^{-1}\right)(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right] \\
=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{x}\right)\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} \\
=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\right)e 
$$
another L'Hospital
$$
= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{-x}{(1+x)^2}-\frac{1}{1+x}}{2x}\right)e 
= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{2(1+x)^2}e = -\frac{e}{2}\\
$$

Comment: Nice. how you recognized to write $-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}+\frac{\tfrac{1}{x+1}}{x}$? I normally write  $x^2(x+1)$ at denominator

Comment: Yes, I tried later to write it in the other way but then one has to use the L'Hospital twice instead of once, and it works too,...honestly it was a coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\dfrac{(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}-e}{x}$$
$$z=(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}\implies \log(z)=\tfrac1x\log(1+x)$$ Now Taylor
$$\log(z)=\tfrac1x\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$z=e^{\log(z)}=e-\frac{e x}{2}+\frac{11 e x^2}{24}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$y=-\frac{e}{2}+\frac{11 e x}{24}+O\left(x^2\right)$$