# Is L'Hopital's rule just a shortcut? OR Are there limits that CANNOT be done without using L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

When I was first taught limits, we were forbidden from using L'Hopital's rule to calculate it. It was regarded as a "shortcut" and not a "real method" to find a limit. Obviously, when you have to take a limit it is often a very easy and intuitive method to find the limit (provided you check the conditions correctly).

However, this led me to think whether this is because it really is just a shortcut that is unnecessary or whether there are places where it is absolutely essential.

Of course, an example of a limit which does require L'Hopital's rule to be solved would answer my question, but especially if it's not true and you CAN always find a limit without L'Hopitals's rule, I want some kind of proof or at least understanding of this.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is a real method. I don't know why you say that it's not.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not, just that it is taught that way. You are expected to solve limits without them for some reason, as if it is just a shortcut that's not "actually necessary." I don't know if this is true, which is why I asked this question

Comment: It can always be done in some other way, if only just by proving the same things over and over again. But that is true for all techniques.

Comment: Given a limit of the form $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ where both $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ _constructively_ exist (meaning for any $\varepsilon$ you can _find_ $\delta$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\right|<\varepsilon$ when $|h|<\delta$), and you _constructively_ know why $f(x)\overset{x\to a}{\to}0$ (and all that for $g$ too), then you could just plug these values for your $\varepsilon$s into the $\varepsilon,\delta$ proof of l'Hopital's rule, right? And have a nice consturctive proof for your limit as your teacher probably want.

Comment: Aside: Every once in a while, you'll see a question here that is of the form: Find $\lim_{h\tp0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h,$ for some messy $f,$  and the first answer is "Use L'Hopital."

Comment: I do not know if it is true universally, but most of the time instead of using L'Hopital's rule you can find a limit by Taylor's decomposition

Comment: The discussion on this question might also be of interest to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118581/lhopitals-rule-and-frac-sin-xx?rq=1

Comment: Any time you are using a theorem, it is just a shorthand for rewriting the proof of the theorem. So all mathematical uses of theorems are just shortcuts - something we can reference to remove redundancy.

Comment: @Kubrick That's really what L'Hôpital's rule is; use first-order Taylor expansion.

Comment: (adding to prets' comment) provided that we understand "the Taylor decomposition" correctly: there are several different forms of Taylor's theorem, and some of them assume greater smoothness than L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule is a very powerful / useful tool, but often it is misused as students don't focus on the conditions of its applicability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, L'Hôpital is a shortcut. If you analyze why it works, in a simplified case we have the following. You want to calculate
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)},
$$
in the case where $f(0)=g(0)=0$. The Taylor expansions of $f,g$ around $0$ are
$$
f(x)=f'(0)x+o(x^2),\qquad g(x)=g'(0)x+o(x^2). 
$$
Then
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(0)x+o(x^2)}{g'(0)x+o(x^2)}=\frac{f'(0)+o(x)}{g'(0)+o(x)}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}.
$$
As an automation system to solve limits, L'Hôpital's rule has at least two problems:

1. It teaches zero intuition. This delves into the philosophy of how and why calculus is taught; and the sad reality is that these in many many cases calculus is taught as a set of automated tools without any understanding. At many (most?) universities students regularly pass calculus with high grades and no understanding of what a derivative or an integral is.
2. In many applications what one needs is not the value of a limit, but an understanding of how the function is behaving at the limit. Here is an easy example of what I mean. Consider
   $$
   \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x. 
   $$
   In many calculus courses this is an automatic L'Hôpital limit, the quotient of the derivatives is $\frac{\cos x}1=\cos x$, and $\cos 0=1$ (that the students will probably obtain with their calculator). If instead one uses approximations, the limit can be seen as
   $$
   \frac{\sin x}x=\frac{x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^5)}x=1-\frac{x^2}6+o(x^4),
   $$
   and we learn that close to $x=0$ the function behaves as $1-\frac{x^2}6$ (telling us not only that the limit is $1$ but, among other things, that the approximation is quadratic).

Comment: Here is an even simpler case: if $f$ and $g$ are linear functions with $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is the quotient of the slopes of $f$ and $g$. This can be shown with algebra. ¶ In general, we replace “linear” with “differentiable” and “slopes” with “derivatives.” In the limit it all works out, thanks to the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: This is not exactly the L'Hospital's Rule, but rather a much simpler variant of it. The rule talks about limit of $f'(x) /g'(x) $ and not about $f'(0)/g'(0)$. The version you are talking of is handled just by using definition of derivative

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I'm aware, which is why I wrote "in a simplified version". Adding more notation to cover the more general cases would only make the argument longer while not changing the main point to be main, which is that L'Hôpital lets you calculate limits blind, without seeing what happens.

Comment: Sorry to say but I did miss the phrase "in a simplified version". If you wish I can delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your first paragraph: as an instructor, I have two learning objectives related to evaluating limits.

- Use the limit laws (sum rule, product rule, etc.) to evaluate limits of functions.
- Use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate limits in indeterminate form.

The first is important because we want students to know how derivatives are calculated “from scratch.” The second is important because L'Hôpital's rule is a powerful theorem.

The trouble is, when you have a very big hammer, everything looks like a nail. Students tend to bang at every limit of any quotient of functions with L'Hôpital's hammer even in situations where:

- the limit isn't in an indeterminate form (leading to an incorrect answer)
- other methods (for example, Taylor series or established trigonometric limits) might resolve the limit more quickly
- using L'Hôpital's rule results in circular reasoning
- functions of several variables are encountered, etc.

For these reasons, we want students to know when to use L'Hôpital *and when not to*. That doesn't diminish the rule itself, though; it just puts the rule in its proper place.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's sad that using higher-order approximations like the Taylor expansion is not on your list.

Comment: (This answer might go more broadly under the theme that some students look at mathematics as a series of formulas to be learned, whereas it's the *logical structure* into which the formulas fit that is what actually matters.)

Comment: @JBL In my head I included Taylor series among “other methods.” But I'll go ahead and make it explicit.